# Grails: how can I convert Tiff image data to png image data?

Tags: grails, groovy, png, base64, tiff

How to convert the tiff image data(base64 string tiff data) to png data? I tried to preview a tiff image data in gsp page but it doesn't work. Here is the code that calls the controller and method in gsp page:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller:'myController', action:'faxDocumentPreview')}"/>
```

Here are my codes in the controller:

```
def faxDocumentPreview(def decodedString){
    def decodedFaxDocuments = decodedString
    decodedFaxDocuments.each{
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment")
        response.contentType = 'image/png' 
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(it)
        out.close()
    }
}

private def decodeFaxPreviews(def faxPreviews) {

    def decodedFaxDocuments = []
    faxPreviews.each {
          decodedFaxDocuments.add(convertBase64ToTiff(it))
    }
    faxDocumentPreview(decodedFaxDocuments)
    return decodedFaxDocuments
}

private def convertBase64ToTiff(def base64String) {
    InputStream inputStream = FileStoreUtils.decodeBase64(base64String);
    return inputStream
}
```

Comment: Maybe use JAI? http://jaypthakkar.blogspot.in/2013/09/converter-tiff-to-jpeg.html

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates, I will try to use JAI library.